# Setting an element's focus only if user has tabbed to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility, keyboard-events

I am trying to make some collapsible accordion containers on my website accessible, but I am running into an issue.

The accordions are controlled by link elements on the page - this way, a keyboard-only user can tab to them and access them. The first issue I ran into was that if a user tabbed to one of the links, the page wouldn't always scroll up to show them which one they had tabbed to. I fixed this issue setting the focus using the following code, which scrolls the link to the top of the viewport:

```
$(".accordion .accordion-item .accordion-heading a").focus(
    function()
    {
        $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 250);
    }
    );
```

The problem I am encountering now is that when a mouse-user clicks on the link, it jumps to the top of the page and does not open the container unless the mouse-user clicks the link again.

Is there a way I can set the focus code above to only fire if the link has been tabbed to? Or, is there a better way of handling the focus issue so that it works for both keyboard-only and mouse users?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is exactly. Can you please add a snippet showing the issue? "The first issue I ran into was that if a user tabbed to one of the links, the page wouldn't always scroll up to show them which one they had tabbed to." > Scrolling to focussed element (was it with the tab key) is AFAIK a browser functionality that is on by default.

Comment: As Laurent says it isn't clear what is causing your problem or the exact behaviour you are trying to describe, could you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem or a link to the page that has the issue. It sounds like whatever function you are using on the accordion isn't working correctly. Also accordions should not be links they should be buttons for correct semantics (unless you provide a link to just the text within the accordion on a seperate page).

Comment: Also if you are intercepting scroll don't animate it, this affects people with anxiety / motion disorders (or ensure it can be disabled and or you use `prefers-reduce-motion` media query)

Comment: @LaurentS. - here is a link to a test version of the page: https://www.williamwoods.edu/test/gallery-index.html

If you scroll down to Previously Hosted Events and click "2019-2020", you'll notice that the page scrolls up, setting that link at the top of the page. You then have to click it again to open it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't link to a page, place a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Links become obsolete, especially when you will have solved your issue the link won't be relevant to your question anymore, and the goal of SO being that your question can help others in the future, obsolescence is not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and advice for using SO - here is a Fiddle with the functionality in question: https://jsfiddle.net/nhpozqr6/ I've also taken @GrahamRitchie's advice and changed the controls to buttons. The issue is, if you scroll down the page and click one of the buttons toward the bottom of the page, it will scroll so that button is at the top of the view-port and you have to click it again to open it. This disrupts mouse-users, who have to reposition and click the same control a second time. Any suggestions on how to approve this would be appreciated. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly a quick apology, having now seen your accordion is built correctly, links with in-page anchors are actually preferable if the accordion is constructed using javascript on page load and falls back to just a list of in page anchor links and content between them.

I am that used to seeing `<a href="#">` on accordion openers and weird accordion implementations I jumped to conclusions, change it back from `<buttons>`!

### Fixing your problem

Probably not the answer you are looking for but remove the `.focus()` function entirely.

It produces strange behaviour where if I have one accordion item open and i tab back with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> quickly scrolling can be really confusing as it jumps around if you tab quicker than the scroll.

One of the golden rules of accessibility is to only adjusted the scroll position on a page if it is expected (i.e. a `return to top` button or using in-page anchors).

In the example and on your website once I disabled the 'scroll to top on focus' the site actually behaved as expected.

I understand why you did it as occasionally a link that is focused appears off the page, however this remedies itself when you tab again or by scrolling down (your site is logical so that if I tab and my focus is not visible I know it is off the page.)

This tends to happen (items not scrolling into view) when the item is just out of sight, by a px or two, it is common and ironically now falls into 'expected' behaviour (another rule, follow accepted and expected behaviour when designing components and pages).

#### If you really want to fix it

In your `focus` function instead of just scrolling to the top of the page whenever an item is focused, check if it is off the page.

Below is an example function I found (not tested) that you can use to check if the item is in the viewport, if it is then don't do anything, if it isn't then do your scroll function.

```
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};
```

So roughly (yet again haven't tested that the correct items are passed in, this is just to give you an idea).

```
$(".accordion .accordion-item .accordion-heading a").focus(
    function()
    { 
        if(isInViewport(this) === false){
             //item is not in the viewport so scroll it into view
            $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top //I would perhaps add a couple of hundred pixels here to make the item appear in a more natural area.
            }, 250); //remove the animation as a further accessibility improvement, animations can be off putting to people with motion or anxiety disorders.
        }
    }
);
```

This fixes your problem as no mouse user will ever be able to click an item that is off the page so they won't ever trigger the scroll event that causes the focus issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the event setting: Instead focus() event you will do a click() event: When you click a link, you'll scroll up. This will solve the problem of both keyboard navigation and mouse clicking;**And this is also more true in terms of accessibility.**

```
$(".accordion .accordion-item .accordion-heading a").click(
function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 250);
}
);
```

Don't forget to change the link setting to a button by adding role=button attribute.
and add aria-expanded attribute.

Comment: he is using the `focus` event to get an item to scroll into view that is off the screen when it receives focus, he can't use the `click` event for that -> "The first issue I ran into was that if a user tabbed to one of the links, the page wouldn't always scroll up to show them which one they had tabbed to. I fixed this issue setting the focus using the following code, which scrolls the link to the top of the viewport"

Comment: The right way at access keyboard navigation is to let the user open an accordion with a click rather than a focus, otherwise it confuses the user

Comment: re-read the question, my answer and my comment, you have misunderstood. The `.focus` is **not used to open the accordion**, it is to scroll things that are off the page into view. His problem comes that when you `click` the `focus` event gets triggered when he doesn't want it to.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie is correct - I didn't want it to scroll when a user clicked on it, I wanted it to scroll into focus when a keyboard-user tabbed to it. :) The issue, though, was that the .focus bit makes the button "jump" to the top of the page when a mouse-user hovered over it, forcing them to move their cursor back over the button and click it again to open the accordion. My plan for now is just to remove that scrolling functionality all together - if what it's doing without that code is expected behavior. I might try that `isInViewport` function later on. Thanks for all the help, everyone! :)

Comment: I've marked @GrahamRitchie's answer as the answer, since it's the one I ultimately went with. The isInViewport function works quite well, but I couldn't get it to fire the scroll function inside of it. It'll fire an alert when I test it, though, so there must just be something weird with my setup. At any rate, I've just decided to disable it for the time being, since it is expected behavior. Thanks again for all your all's help! :D

Comment: @W. J. Terrell - check whether `$(this)` in `$(this).offset().top` is pointing to the right item, it could be pointing to something other than the element.